# How to replace all "&int-int" with the respective string slices in an input string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a school project question (for Python) that goes like this:

Given a string_input such as "abcd&1-4efg", the function must remove the "&1-4" and insert the string slice from 1 to 4 where the "&1-4" was.

eg. if string_input = "abcd&1-4efg",

1. "&1-4" is removed.
2. The remaining characters are indexed as follows: a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3, e=4, f=5, g=6
3. The new string becomes:
   "abcdbcdeefg"

I've managed to write a long chunk of code to do this, but I'm wondering if anyone has any more efficient solutions?

Things to note:

1. The instructions can include double digits (eg. &10-15)
2. If the index isn't found, the returned string should print "?" for every missing index
   (eg. "abcd&5-10efgh" would return "abcdfgh???efgh")
3. Intructions can be back-to-back (eg. "&10-15abcdef&1-5&4-5pqrs")

The code I've written is:

```
def expand(text):
text += "|"
import string
digits_dash = string.digits + "-"

idx_ref_str = ""
replace_list = []
record_val = False
output_to_list = []
instruct = ""
and_idx_mark = 0

#builds replace_list & idx_ref_list
for idx in range(len(text)):
    if text[idx] == "&" and record_val==True:
        output_to_list.append(instruct)
        output_to_list.append(and_idx_mark)
        replace_list.append(output_to_list)
        output_to_list, instruct, inst_idx, and_idx_mark = [],"",0,0

        and_idx_mark = idx
        continue
    elif text[idx] == "&":
        record_val = True
        and_idx_mark = idx
        continue

    #executes if currently in instruction part
    if record_val == True:
        #adds to instruct
        if text[idx] in digits_dash:
            instruct += text[idx]
        #take info, add to replace list
        else:
            output_to_list.append(instruct)
            output_to_list.append(and_idx_mark)
            replace_list.append(output_to_list)
            output_to_list, instruct, inst_idx, and_idx_mark, record_val = [],"",0,0,False

    #executes otherwise
    if record_val == False:
        idx_ref_str += text[idx]

idx_ref_str = idx_ref_str[:-1]
text = text[:-1]

#converts str to int indexes in replace list[x][2]
for item in replace_list:
    start_idx = ""
    end_idx = ""
    #find start idx
    for char in item[0]:
        if char in string.digits:
            start_idx += char
        elif char == "-":
            start_idx = int(start_idx)
            break
    #find end idx
    for char in item[0][::-1]:
        if char in string.digits:
            end_idx = char + end_idx
        elif char == "-":
            end_idx = int(end_idx)
            break

    start_end_list = [start_idx,end_idx]
    item+=start_end_list

#split text into parts in list
count = 0
text_block = ""
text_block_list = []

idx_replace = 0

for char in text:
    if char == "&":
        text_block_list.append(text_block)
        text_block = ""
        count += len(replace_list[idx_replace][0])
        idx_replace +=1
    elif count > 0:
        count -= 1
    else:
        text_block += char

text_block_list.append(text_block)

#creates output str
output_str = ""

for idx in range(len(text_block_list)-1):
    output_str += text_block_list[idx]

    #creates to_add var to add to output_str
    start_repl = replace_list[idx][1]
    end_repl = replace_list[idx][1] + len(replace_list[idx][0])

    find_start = replace_list[idx][2]
    find_end = replace_list[idx][3]

    if end_idx >= len(idx_ref_str):
        gap = end_idx + 1 - len(idx_ref_str)
        to_add = idx_ref_str[find_start:] + "?" * gap
    else:
        to_add = idx_ref_str[find_start:find_end+1]
    
    output_str += to_add

output_str += text_block_list[-1]

return output_str
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You have done a great job explaining your task and providing your code, but I am not sure what your actual question is. Is there something that throws an error, or not working?

Comment: Hi @JonSG, I'm just wondering if there's a better way to code this. The exam expects me to solve the problem in about 15-20mins, and this code took me over an hour to figure out haha. If you or anyone can think of a more efficient solution, I'm all ears :)

Comment: If the code you have works and you want feedback on how to improve it, the best place to ask is: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JonSG Oh cool, I didn't know there was a separate site for that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. Always open to criticism.

```
import re

s = 'abcd&1-4efg'

c = re.compile('&[0-9]+-[0-9]+')

if (m := c.search(s)):
    a, b = m.span()
    left = s[:a]
    right = s[b:]
    o = [int(x) for x in m.group(0)[1:].split('-')]
    mid = (left+right)[o[0]:o[1]+1]
    print(left + mid + right)
```

Comment: Can the regex be like `&\d+-\d+` and also, seems likr u r using the `c` only once. So why can't u put it in the same parentheses of if statement?

Comment: Yes - If you prefer that. Of course, you'd have to declare the string as raw

Comment: And it also doesn't look like it can return `?` at the place of index variables if the given index is invalid...

Comment: There's nothing in the original question to suggest that the input string might be invalid or indeed what should happen if that is the case. Happy to update the code if the original questioner wants to explain how that should be handled.

Comment: I've done some research @GhostOps. [0-9] is correct in the context of this question. \d will work for the given example but actually means much more than [0-9]. I thought you would have known that

Comment: yeah, \d also matches decimal i guess, even i dont know much about regex, i thought [0-9] and \d are same... but whats the difference? and also sry for being a nerd